# Replace special characters recursively bash

Tags: bash, loops, tr, mv

I'm trying to find all files and folders in a certain folder and all sub-folders and replace all special characters. All spaces should be replaced with dots and everything else should just be deleted. I've tried a few different ways but when I use "mv" it doesn't seem to preserve the directory structure and when I use "rename" along with "find" it doesn't want to go recursively.

The closest I've gotten is this:

```
for f in **/; do mv "$f" `echo $f | tr " " . | tr -dc '[:alnum:].'`; done
```

But I think the loop is broken somewhere as it adds filenames together and places the result in the parent directory.

Comment: Dots should be deleted too?

Comment: You want to replace all special characters from file names, not from files contents, right?

Comment: because you're removing slashes, of course it won't remember the folder structure.

Comment: dots should stay. all special characters from just filenames, correct.

Comment: What _exactly_ count as "special characters"?  For example, is `-` (hyphen) or `_` (underscore) special?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
find . -depth -execdir rename 's/\s/./g; s/[^[:alnum:]./]//g' {} +
```

A couple of points here:

- `-depth` -- traverse the directory hierarchy depth-first. This ensures that you rename the files in a folder *before* you rename the folder
- `-execdir` -- executes the command *in the subdirectory* -- `{}` will now be `./filename` instead of `./dir1/dir2/filename`
- this is the perl-flavoured `rename`, check your man page.

Comment: Your comment about it being perl flavored, would that be the reason it adds a dot to the beginning of every file?

Comment: probably not. The filename at that point is probably `./filename`, and you're probably removing the slash.

Comment: I kind of cheated and broke your solution down into 2 different find lines. One for each rename statement. The first one works great but the second one says "Substitution pattern not terminated at (user-supplied code)."